# Outlook 2007 - Cannot start Outlook - Cannot open the Outlook window

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I went to open Outlook 2007 on my Windows 7 32bit machine and it came up with this error:

`Cannot start Microsoft Office Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The set of folders cannot be opened. The information store could not be opened.`

I have deleted and created a new profile in Control Panel > Mail but it still doesn't want to work properly but it still comes up with this message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had it happen to me this morning.  (Win7 x64, Outlook 2007).  The message can be caused by a number of issues like a [compatibility setting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252304) or a [corrupted outlook profile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022778) file.  In my case, I had to run the following at a command prompt:

```
Outlook.exe /resetnavpane
```

The technical issues surrounding the Navigation Pane can be found at Microsoft's Support site [KB2022778](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022778).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried safe mode?

a) Hold Ctrl and click Outlook from start menu

or

b) "Outlook.exe /safe" from command prompt

Comment: Yep I tried that but it came up with the same thing. I managed to sort it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have sorted it. Changed the .pst in Control Panel > Mail and created a new default pst file and it seems to be working fine for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I tried hard to fix it but it not work for me. Then I did this and **it worked for me**

Resolution

1. Uninstall Program Microsoft office 2007
2. restart
3. Install new Microsoft office 2010
4. Set new outlook again